# How to make sure td-agent doesn't send to treasuredata by default?

Tags: fluentd

According to http://www.fluentd.org/faqs, td-agent is

```
Preconfigured with a couple of recommended settings, and sending data to  
Treasure Data by default (can be modified).
```

Where is this enabled by default? I don't see any entry in the config files to turn this default off. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

First section in the default config files (after installing the *td-agent* package) is using plugin **type tdlog**. This plugin sends the data to TD (if *apikey* is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

td-agent is also open-sourced, and you can see the default config at here:
https://github.com/treasure-data/omnibus-td-agent/blob/master/templates/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf

You can turn off that default configuration by editing /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf after installation.

Answer (score 0):

use [`fluent-bit`](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit) it does not have **tdlog** set at all.